# Smallest near triangulation of the plane with an external face of size $4$ for which all interior vertices have minimum degree $5$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

Consider the near-triangulation $G$ with an external face of size $4$. What is the minimum number of interior vertices for which G has minimum degree 5 as to those vertices?  The degrees of the $4$ boundary vertices are in no way constrained--they can be as low or as high as necessary. Is there an easy proof of the result, whatever it is? Standard use of Euler's formula provides guidance but doesn't seem to pin down an answer, at least by my reckoning. An easy upper bound is $8$ interior vertices because deleting any edge in the icosahedron results in a $G$ meeting the constraint.